# How can I mask first and last few digits in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanna mask the first and last few digits for a column and only show the middle part of it. how can I do that?
The below code is what I saw very common but what it does is mask the middle and only show either the first or last digits.

```
ALTER TABLE Data.Membership  
ALTER COLUMN LastName ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(2,"xxxx",0)');
```

Let's say the example of value is 12345678900123 I want it to be xxxx-567890-xxxx
The data type is string -> varchar ( 14 )

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you add sample number data?  What is the range of values which can appear in the table?

Comment: Let's say the example of value is 1234567890123
I want it to be  xxxx-56789-xxxx @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Will it always be a 13 digit number?

Comment: is string @jarlh

Comment: 14 digit @jarlh

Comment: 1234567890123 is 13 digits...

Comment: oh sorry I misscount, it is 14

Comment: I don't think if that's possible with the available masking functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ALTER TABLE Data.Membership
ALTER COLUMN LastName nvarchar(14) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION= 'partial(3,"XXXX",3)');
```